# Multi contains and filter

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need to make a difficult request with lot of contains but I don't understand how to filter results on contains.

My tables are like that:

**Menus** HasMany **Sousmenus**

**Sousmenus** HasMany **Droits**

**Droits** BelongsToMany **Roles**

**Roles** BelongsToMany **Services**

I Know the Services_id and I want the menus contain Sousmenus contain Droits contain Role where:

Roles linked to my Service_id

Droits linked to these roles

Sousmenus linked to these droits

and menus linked to this sous_menus.

It's very difficult to explain.

**EDIT:** I tried that but it doesn't work:

```
$menus = TableRegistry::get('Menus');
$query = $menus->find()->contain(['Sousmenus.Droits.Roles.Services'])->matching('Sousmenus.Droits.Roles.Services', function ($q) {
    return $q->where(['Services.id' => 6]);
});
```

Comment: What did you try? It should be somathing like `$query->contain(['Droits.Sousmenus.Menus', 'Droits.Roles.Services'])` http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#loading-associations

Comment: Thanks for answer. My problem is not about getting all the results. I want to filter all these results. I want only one service (I have the ID) I want the roles of this service not all the roles, I want the Droits of these roles etc etc.
I tried to filter with ->where() but I can't filter my contained models with it.
In final I need an array wich begins by my menus which contain its sousmenus which contain Droits

Comment: possible duplicate of [find on associated model's condition CakePHP 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799094/find-on-associated-models-condition-cakephp-3-0)

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried it. First post edited for the code.

 And it returns all the results for every Services not only the 6.

Comment: "_the 6_" (as in 6 rows), or "_the ones with the id 6_"? There's a big difference! In case it's the latter, what does the generated query look like? ps, you should use @username tags to ensure that the one you are "talking" to will be notified (I just saw you comment by chance, as there will be no notifications sent for automated comments like the "possible duplicate" one).