# Cakephp not loading belongsToMany association beetween two Models

Tags: cakephp, model-view-controller, cakephp-3.0

I just started my project with cakephp3.0. I startet with the Users. I put a function isAuthorized in the UsersController which should validate if the User is permitted to view other users, to edit other users and so on.

I created a table "userprivileges" where all possible privileges, which can be assigned to a user are listed. 
The table is "userprivileges" is:

```
id | controller | function
```

Next I want to group the priviliges into roles.
I created following table: "userprivilegeroles"

```
id | role
```

Next I created the BTM-Table: "userprivileges_userprivilegeroles"

```
id | userprivilegerole_id | userprivilegerole_id
```

The User is linked to the `userprivilegeroles` table, so I need to search if the requested controller/function is view-able for the user.

I tried like this:

```
$this->loadModel('Userprivilegeroles');
$userprivilegeroles = $this->Userprivilegeroles->find('all', [
    'conditions' => [
        'Userprivileges.controller' => $this->request->controller,
        'Userprivileges.function' => $this->request->action], 
    'contain' => ['Userprivileges']
]);
```

Now this fails with following error:

> Userprivilegeroles is not associated with Userprivileges.

There is a little more description, where I can search for the problem prompted to the 500 page.

> - The class for the specified table does not exist.
> - The Table was created with a typo: TableRegistry::get('Atricles');
> - The class file has a typo in the name or incorrect namespace: class Atricles extends Table
> - The file containing the class has a typo or incorrect casing: Atricles.php
> - The Table was used using associations but the association has a typo: $this->belongsTo('Atricles')
> - The table class resides in a Plugin but no plugin notation was used in the association definition.

Lets go for it one by one:

> The class for the specified table does not exist.

It does:

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class UserprivilegerolesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config){
        $this->belongsToMany('Userprivileges', [
            'joinTable' => 'userprivileges_userprivilegeroles',
            'className' => 'Userprivileges'
        ]);
    }       
}
```

Next

> The Table was created with a typo: TableRegistry::get('Atricles');

No.

> The class file has a typo in the name or incorrect namespace: class Atricles extends Table

no.

> The file containing the class has a typo or incorrect casing: Atricles.php

no. its in src/Model/Table/Userprivilegeroles.php

> The Table was used using associations but the association has a typo: $this->belongsTo('Atricles')

See above. I don't see a typo.

> The table class resides in a Plugin but no plugin notation was used in the association definition.

As described, I called it from the UsersController.

Can anyone help me finding, why the association doesn't work as expected? Maybe I am to much stuck in the cakephp 2.0 ORM, but I am almost sure that I did the association like described in the cookbook.

I've searched already and found some other issues with the belongstomany association. But they all handle problems with saving data. I want to search data, so I see no connection there.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem you're having, I think you might save yourself a lot of typing, without really losing any useful specificity, if you called the tables simply "privileges" and "roles" and "privileges_roles".

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Actually, I knowingly decided to do so, because priviliges and roles will be used in another context again. So I needed to seperate beetween the user-related context and other parts of the App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the filename *is* incorrect, filenames must match classnames (PSR-4), so it should be `UserprivilegerolesTable.php`. The warning notes may need some fixing or further explanation, as they are a little misleading by not using the `Table` suffix.

Once you've fixed that you'll stumble over the next problem, contained `belongsToMany` and `hasMany` associations cannot be used in conditions, as they are retrieved in a separate query, you'll have to use `matching()` instead.

- [**Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Filtering by Associated Data**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data)
- **[How to filter by conditions for associated models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799094/find-on-associated-models-condition-cakephp-3-0)**