# Filtering data based on selected row of associated table in cake 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1

I have three tables:

1 lab_categories (columns include `id`, `category`)

```
class LabCategoriesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('lab_categories');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->hasMany('LabTests', [
            'foreignKey' => 'lab_category_id'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Laboratories', [
            'foreignKey' => 'lab_category_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'laboratory_id',
            'joinTable' => 'laboratories_lab_categories'
        ]);
    }}
```

2 laboratories(columns include `id`,`name`)

```
class LaboratoriesTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('laboratories');
        $this->displayField('name');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->hasMany('LabRefValues', [
            'foreignKey' => 'laboratory_id'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('LabCategories', [
            'foreignKey' => 'laboratory_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'lab_category_id',
            'joinTable' => 'laboratories_lab_categories'
        ]);
    }}
```

3 laboratories_lab_categories (columns include `id`, `laboratory_id`, `lab_category_id`)

```
class LaboratoriesLabCategoriesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('laboratories_lab_categories');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
        $this->belongsTo('Laboratories', [
            'foreignKey' => 'laboratory_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('LabCategories', [
            'foreignKey' => 'lab_category_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }}
```

I want to be able to select `lab_categories.name` associated with a specified `laboratory.id` so as to be able to add it to an ajax call up I created. 
I want to generate a result similar to what this query will generate;
Select lab_categories.id,category
From lab_categories
Join laboratories_lab_categories
where laboratories_lab_categories.laboratory_id=$id
AND laboratories_lab_categories.lab_category_id=lab_categories.id

I am using `cakephp 3.1` and the tables were baked. I have search through related question but non was applicable for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find on associated model's condition CakePHP 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799094/find-on-associated-models-condition-cakephp-3-0)

Comment: Thank you very much, I was not adding the \Cake\ORM\Query to my function