# Cakephp: How to get 2nd level conditional contain without intermediate entities

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I execute the following request:

```
$agPoi = $this->Agpois->get($agPoiId, [
    'contain' => [
        'Agpoititles.Agthemelanguages' => function ($q) use ($languageId) {
            return $q->where([
                'language_id' => $languageId,
            ]);

        }
    ]
]);
```

Surprisingly, it returns me all `agpoititles` with only one containing a not empty `aghtemelanguage` object for which `'language_id' => $languageId`.
But I'm not interested by `agpoititles` not containing an `agthemelanguage` object.
How to modify the request to only the ones I want?

**EDIT**

Agpois `hasMany` Agpoititles
AgpoiTitles `belongsTo` Agthemelanguages
Agthemelanguages `hasOne` Agpoititles

SO I expect to get agPoi with THE `Agpoititles` for which its `agthemelanguage->language_id` = $languageId

**Edit 2**

So I tried to use matching() and it works if you pay attention to look for the result in `_matchingData` as it's explained in the doc ;).

```
$agPoi = $this->Agpois->find()
              ->contain(['Agpoititles.Agthemelanguages'])
              ->matching('Agpoititles.Agthemelanguages', function ($q) use ($languageId, $poiId) {
                   return $q->where([
                      'Agpois.id' => $poiId,
                      'language_id' => $languageId
                      ]);
                  }
              )
              ->first();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find on associated model's condition CakePHP 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799094/find-on-associated-models-condition-cakephp-3-0)

Comment: please explain the relationships between the models

Comment: @ndm I think it's not relate to my problem as I find what I need but Cake returns more than what I need.

Comment: @arilia I edit my post.

Comment: It's the same problem, just for a containment rather than the main table... give it a try.

Comment: @ndm but I'm not a belongsToMany association so I don't see why to use matching(). I don't really understand what you try to tell me. Sorry.

Comment: The type of association doesn't matter. You want to filter by an association (as far as I understood), and that's what `Query::matching()` (and `Query::innerJoinWith()`) is there for.

Comment: @ndm: ah ok. I look at it.

Comment: @ndm I edited my post. It still doesn't work :(.

Comment: @ndm, sorry, I just didn't look in the right area in the results set.