# query including many tables cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Using cakephp 3 I want to have the same result that I will have if I execute the query below (Get all paiements of appartements  that belongs to Complex XX) :

```
SELECT p.*
FROM immeubles i inner join appartements a on i.id=a.immeuble_id
inner join paiements p on p.appartement_id = a.id
where i.complex_id=4
```

tables used are :

```
Immeubles (id,name,complex_id(Foreign Key));
Appartements(id, num,immeuble_id(foreign key))
paiements(id,montant,appartement_id(foreign key))
```

I tried first to extract all appartements that belongs to complex=4 by using the code below but i don't know how to concatenate the results with the table Paiements in order to show all fields of paiements :

```
$this->Appartements->find()
->join([
'i' => [
'table' => 'Immeubles',
'type' => 'inner',
'conditions' => [
'i.id=Appartements.immeuble_id',
'i.complex_id' => 4
]]]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find on associated model's condition CakePHP 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799094/find-on-associated-models-condition-cakephp-3-0)

Comment: this post shows the relation between 2 tables only.Me I'm having problem to relate 3 tables. thanks anyway

Comment: Just check the linked docs, it shows how deep associations can be targeted. I'll update the answer though and mention how to target them.

Comment: I'm working on it , I have tried to execute the query manually by doing this :-------
`$this->Paiements->query("SELECT p.* from immeubles i inner join appartements a on i.id=a.immeuble_id inner join paiements p on p.appartement_id = a.id"." where i.complex_id= 4");`
----------------
this solution doesn't work, the query returns all records so he doesn't take on consideration the clause where.