# CakePHP pass condition on hasMany associated Model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.3

I have to make join and then pass conditions if there is hasMany associated Model.

It gives unknown field in condition, if we pass condition on hasMany associated Model fields.
Is there a way to pass conditions on hasMany associated Model in cakePHP ?

Comment: try 'ModelName.field_name' => ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter by conditions for associated models?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799094/how-to-filter-by-conditions-for-associated-models)