# CakePHP : query printing same values twice

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.2

I'm working on CakePHP 3.2.

I have `categories`, `products`, `seller_products` table and their association are

```
categories->hasMany('Products');
seller_products->hasMany('Products');
```

I have to retrieve all products group by category where seller_products.stock > 0

This is what I'm doing

```
$pros1 = $this->Products->Categories->find()
          ->where([
            'Categories.status' => 0,
          ])
          ->contain([
            'Products.SellerProducts', 'Subcategories', 'Subcategories.ProductTypes'
          ])
          ->matching('Products.SellerProducts', function(\Cake\ORM\Query $q) {
            return $q->where(['SellerProducts.stock >' => 0]);
          });
```

but on debugging, it is returning same values twice.
`foreach($pros1 as $p){debug($p);}` is printing same values twice

```
/src/Controller/PagesController.php (line 120)

object(App\Model\Entity\Category) {

    'id' => (int) 1,
    'title' => 'Electronics',
    'description' => '',
    'icon' => 'fa-television',
    'status' => (int) 0,
    'created' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {
       .........
     }

/src/Controller/PagesController.php (line 120)

object(App\Model\Entity\Category) {

    'id' => (int) 1,
    'title' => 'Electronics',
    'description' => '',
    'icon' => 'fa-television',
    'status' => (int) 0,
    'created' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {
       .........
     }
```

and `debug(count($pros1))` prints 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the docs:

> As this function will create an `INNER JOIN`, you might want to consider
>   calling `distinct` on the find query as you might get duplicate rows if
>   your conditions don’t exclude them already. This might be the case,
>   for example, when the same users comments more than once on a single
>   article.

**[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Filtering by Associated Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data)**

In your case there are multiple matching products that belong to the same category. So, either use a distinct select for the tables primary key, or group by it ([**there may be no difference between the two**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164319/is-there-any-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct)).

```
$pros1 = $this->Products->Categories
    ->find()
    ->distinct('Categories.id')
    // ...
```

```
    // ...
    ->matching(/* ... */)
    ->group('Categories.id');
```

See also

- **[API > \Cake\Database\Query::distinct()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_distinct)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Query::group()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_group)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Query::matching()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.ORM.Query.html#_matching)**

Comment: thanks ndm. but matching is not working. It is still showing products with `SellerProducts.stock = 0`

Comment: @AnujTBE That's a different question though.That's not how matching works. Matching filters the parent records, if you contain child records (`SellerProducts`) and want only specific ones, then you have to filter them too. See **http://stackoverflow.com/a/26800203/1392379**