# How to filter containments by associated data?

Tags: cakephp, associations, filtering, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I want to get associated only if the second level associated data respect the given condition.

The query will maybe better explain what I try to do.

```
$selSite = $this->Sites->get($selSiteId, [
    'contain' => [
        'Agplans.Products' => function ($q) {
            return $q
            ->where([
                'Products.type' => 'hosting',
            ]);
        }
    ]
]);
```

So I expect an `agplan` only if its associated product matches the condition.

But the result is:

```
'agplans' => [
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Agplan) {

        'id' => (int) 20,
        'product_id' => (int) 4,
        'product' => null,
        ...,

    },
    (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\Agplan) {

        'id' => (int) 21,
        'site_id' => (int) 64,
        'product_id' => (int) 75,
        'product' => object(App\Model\Entity\Product) {

            'id' => (int) 75,
            ...,

        },
        ...,

    }
],
```

My problem here is to get `agplan[0]` with a `product => null`.
It's not what I understood from the [doc](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#passing-conditions-to-contain).
How to get the `agplan` with `'product' => object(App\Model\Entity\Product)` only?

Comment: Sounds like **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799094/how-to-filter-by-conditions-for-associated-models** to me.

Comment: @ndm I don't think it's the same problem. Here I don't want to get few sites for which associated matches the condition, I only `get` one specific site. I just want here to filter out its associated. What the [doc](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#passing-conditions-to-contain) explains telling `It is also possible to restrict **deeply-nested associations** using the dot notation:`. I don't see what I didn't understand here.

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to what @ndm pointed me out I understood that I have to build my query like that:

```
$selSite = $this->Sites->get($selSiteId, [
    'contain' => [
        'Agplans.Products',
        'Agplans' => function ($q) {
            return $q
            ->matching('Products', function ($q) {
                return $q
                ->where([
                    'type' => 'hosting',
                ]);
            });
        }
    ]
]);
```

That way, I only get `agplans` matching the given `product`.
Anyway, I find the CakePHP doc not clear on the contain feature about restricting associated.

Comment: I guess it could possibly be a little confusing for people that aren't that familiar with containments yet, so you may want to [**report this as an issue**](https://github.com/cakephp/docs/issues), a small hint about what "_restrict deeply-nested associations_" refers to, and that it shouldn't be confused with filtering by associated data surely wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @ndm, Is it to be considered as an issue? I currently proposed to clarify the doc on that point.

Comment: Well, "issue" certainly can mean a lot of different things based on the context, I just wanted to refer to GitHub tickets, which are called "issues". I should maybe choose better wording in the future.

Comment: @ndm ok I do it.