# Inner join for associations in cakephp 3 using contain()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

In Cakephp 3, how to make has-many association follow inner join type for contain(). For matching(), i am getting duplicates and the result of association collection is not nested

Comment: You want to get data which at least one row of the associated table? If so you can put a where clause in which you can check the count from sub-query. This will behave like the inner join. Because as @ndm says "There is no such thing as INNER joined hasMany containments"

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as `INNER` joined `hasMany` containments, as the CakePHP ORM will use an additional query to retrieve containments of that type.

If you get duplicates when using `matching()`, then use `distinct()` or `group()`. If you need to retrieve associated records additionally to matching, then use `contain()` too, and add conditions for the containment if necessary.

See also

- **[How to filter by conditions for associated models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799094/how-to-filter-by-conditions-for-associated-models)**
- [**Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Filtering by Associated Data**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data)
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Selecting Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Passing Conditions to Contain](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#passing-conditions-to-contain)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Query::distinct()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_distinct)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Query::group()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_group)**