# cakephp3- unable to fetch all acos for an aros

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, acl, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to fetch all acos for a given aros.

Cakephp version I'm using is **3.4**

As ACL is not built-in I use this [plugin](https://github.com/ivanamat/cakephp3-aclmanager).

I'm able to fetch all acos available by using this code:

```
   $acos = $this->Acl->Aco->find('all', array('order' => 'Acos.lft ASC', 'recursive' => -1))
           ->contain(['Aros' ]) 
           ->toArray();
```

And, following is the code I wrote to fetch all acos for a given aros

```
     $acos = $this->Acl->Aco->find('all', array('order' => 'Acos.lft ASC', 'recursive' => -1))
           ->contain(['Aros'  => function ($q) {
                        return $q->where(['id' => 1]);
                    } ]) 
           ->toArray();
```

But it does not return the correct result. Instead, it returns all the acos (the same result the above code returns)

Can anyone help me identify the issue? Thanks!

Comment: @arilia Added code.

Comment: @G.J Can you have a look at this?

Comment: You may want to have a look at **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799094/how-to-filter-by-conditions-for-associated-models**, sounds like you want to filter by associated data. ps, you're mixing in CakePHP 2.x stuff, there is no `recursive` option in CakePHP 3.x anymore.