# CakePHP 3 - Query builder properly not working for HasMany associations

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

> Table : **Services**

```
+-----+--------------+
| id  |  title       |
+-----+--------------+
| 1   | Service 1    |
+-----+--------------+
| 2   | Service 2    |
+-----+--------------+
```

> Table : **Workshops** { HasMany `WorkshopServices` }

```
+-----+---------------+
| id  |  title        |
+-----+---------------+
| 1   | Workshop 1    |
+-----+---------------+
| 2   | Workshop 2    |
+-----+---------------+
```

> Table : **WorkshopServices**

```
+-----+--------------+-------------+
| id  |  workshop_id |  service_id |
+-----+--------------+-------------+
| 1   |  1           |  1          |
+-----+--------------+-------------+
| 2   |  1           |  2          |
+-----+--------------+-------------+
```

I want to find `Workshops` by `service_id`

> **My Query**

```
$this->Workshops->find()
    ->contain([
        'WorkshopServices'
    ])
    ->where([
        'WorkshopServices.service_id IN'=>[1,2,3]
    ]);
```

> **Query Result**

```
Unknown column `WorkshopServices.service_id` in 'where clause'
```

Actually `Workshops` table is not generating any `JOIN` with `WorkshopServices` table.

How can I write the query to get proper result from `Query Builder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I updated @GabrielFerreira's query and Grouping the rows by `WorkshopServices.workshop_id`, This solution meet my Problem

```
$array = [1,2,3];

$this->Workshops->find()
    ->select([
          'title'=>'Workshops.title',
          'id'=>'Workshops.id',
    ])
    ->matching('WorkshopServices', function ($q) use($array) {
       return $q->where(['WorkshopServices.service_id IN' => $array]);
    })
    ->group(['WorkshopServices.workshop_id']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use matching:

```
$array = [1,2,3];

$this->Workshops->find()
    ->matching('WorkshopServices', function ($q) use($array) {
       return $q->where(['WorkshopServices.service_id IN' => $array])
    });
```

Comment: But sometimes results array is returning duplicates `Workshops` (When selecting Multiple services) :( Please update your Query...

Comment: use distinct before matching

Comment: @GabrielFerreira, won't that return only a single WorkshopService with any give Workshop? It's not completely clear from the question, but my assumption is the OP would want all services associated with a workshop. One solution might be to use the function you've shown, but on the containment instead of through matching, and then map/reduce the results to eliminate those which have no services?

Comment: I updated this query and added an answer. @GabrielFerreira

Comment: I updated this query and added an answer. @GregSchmidt