# CakePHP 3.6.11: Where clause of joined tables

Tags: php, cakephp, foreign-keys, cakephp-3.6

I have these 3 tables:

customers:

[customerstable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYkTQ.png)

services:

[servicestable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Najgx.png)

customerservices:

[customerservicestable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PxYs.png)

With this relation in `CustomerservicesTable.php`:

```
$this->belongsTo('Customers')
            ->setForeignKey('customerid');

$this->belongsTo('Services')
            ->setForeignKey('serviceid');
```

In `Customers` edit page I want to add a table with the `Services` of the specific customer (and then add new, edit existing etc).

So in `Template\Customers\edit.ctp` I have this table:

```
<h3><?= __('Services') ?></h3>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Date') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Service') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Price') ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="actions"><?= __('Actions') ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($services as $service): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= h($service->created) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($service->title) ?></td>
                <td><?= $this->Number->format($service->price) ?></td>
                <td class="actions">
                    <?= $this->Html->link(__('View'), ['action' => 'view', $customer->id]) ?>
                    <?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $customer->id]) ?>
                    <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $customer->id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $customer->id)]) ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and in the `edit` function of `Controller\CustomersController.php` I have added these lines:

```
//Get customerservices for specific customer
        $servicesTable = TableRegistry::get('Services');
        $services = $servicesTable->find('all');//->where(['Services.Customerservices.id =' => $this->data['Customers']['id']]);

        $this->set(compact('services'));
```

And I have commented the `where` part. How I can change it in order to get only the services that belong to the specific customer? using the `customerservicesTable`?

And after that can I edit directly the `CustomerservicesController.php` to implement the add,edit functions of this table?

**EDIT**

After ndm suggestion I changed it like this:

```
//Get customerservices for specific customer
        $servicesTable = TableRegistry::get('Services');
        $services = $servicesTable->find()->matching('Customerservices', function(\Cake\ORM\Query $q) {
                return $q->where(['Customerservices.customerid' => $this->data['Customers']['id']]);
            });
```

But its not working. Probably the `$this->data['Customers']['id']` is not working because if I replace it with 1 (the Customer id) its working as expected. Any idea why is not working?

Comment: You may want to have a look at **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799094/how-to-filter-by-conditions-for-associated-models**

Comment: @ndm thank you, can you check the edited post please for an update?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive *what* is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$servicesTable = TableRegistry::get('Services');

$customerId = $this->data['Customers']['id'];
// how about $this->request->getData('Customer.id') ?

// pass variable to function with `use`
$services = $servicesTable->find()->matching('Customerservices', function(\Cake\ORM\Query $q) use ($customerId) {
    return $q->where(['Customerservices.customerid' => $customerId]);
});
```

If you are not sure that `$this->data['Customers']['id']` contains what you expect, just have a look what’s in there:

```
debug($this->data['Customers']);

// or
debug($this->data);

// or
print_r($this->data['Customers']);
```

If this is data published by the Request Object, have a look here: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-body-data

```
// An input with a name attribute equal to 'MyModel[title]' is accessible at
$title = $this->request->getData('MyModel.title');
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding `use ($id)` and `$id` instead of `$this->data['Customers']['id']` :

```
//Get customerservices for specific customer
        $servicesTable = TableRegistry::get('Services');
        $services = $servicesTable->find()->matching('Customerservices', function(\Cake\ORM\Query $q) use ($id) {
                return $q->where(['Customerservices.customerid' => $id]);
            });
```