# CakePHP 3.6.11: store selected value from dropdown to database

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.6

I have these 3 tables:

customers:

[customerstable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYkTQ.png)

services:

[servicestable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Najgx.png)

customerservices:

[customerservicestable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PxYs.png)

With this relation in `CustomerservicesTable.php`:

```
$this->belongsTo('Customers')
            ->setForeignKey('customerid');

$this->belongsTo('Services')
            ->setForeignKey('serviceid');
```

In `Template\Customerservices\add.ctp` I have a form with a dropdown and a numeric field :

```
<div class="customerservices form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($customerservice) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add transaction') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('Transaction type',array('options' => $servicesList));
            echo $this->Form->control('price');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

in `Controller\CustomerservicesController.php` :

```
public function add($customerid = null)
    {

        $customerservice = $this->Customerservices->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $customerservice->customerid = $customerid;
            $customerservice->serviceid = //get selection from dropdown
            if ($this->Customerservices->save($customerservice)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The customerservice has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The customerservice could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('customerservice'));

        $servicesList = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Services')->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('servicesList'));
    }
```

How can I replace the comment in order to save the `serviceid` which is selected in the dropdown control?

(secondary question is it possible to hide the `price` field depending on the dropdown selection?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like I told you [couple of minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52538373/1512445).

Change the `input` like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('transaction_type',array('type'=>'select','options' => $servicesList));
```

In your `Controller`:

```
public function add($customerid = null)
{
    …
    $customerservice->serviceid = $this->request->getData('transaction_type');
    …
}
```

Hiding the `price` field depending on the selection in the dropdown seems like a job for the client side, which can be done with JavaScript. For example in jQuery:

```
$('#transaction_type').on('change', function() {
    // hide element with ID #price if value of select with ID #transaction_type is `holymoly`
    // and show element if value is anything else
    $('#price').toggle(this.value === 'holymoly');
});
```