# how to add conditions inside contain in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Here I am getting the all PurchaseRequisitionProducts then I am checking the condition in contain that 'PurchaseOrder.po_type'=>1 then I am getting empty PurchaseOrder array inside PurchaseRequisitionProducts for PurchaseOrder.po_type !=1. Till here the condition is right but i also have to remove those PurchaseRequisitionProducts whose PurchaseOrder is empty or null. So inside contain how can i add the condition like 'PurchaseRequisitionProducts.PurchaseOrder IS NOT NULL'

```
    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['PurchaseOrderProducts.PurchaseOrder'=>function($p){
        return $p->where(['PurchaseOrder.po_type'=>1]);
        },
        ];
    $pr_product = $this->paginate($this->PurchaseRequisitionProducts);
```

Comment: Have a look at **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799094/how-to-filter-by-conditions-for-associated-models**.

Comment: @ndm my issue is not there. I have to remove the array or main pagination array if there contain is blank or not available.