# CakePHP ORM find query with multi contain (hasMany relationship) conditions

Tags: cakephp, orm

For the example lets take 3 tables:

1. country_of_residence_history (related to users with belongsTo association type)
2. users (related to transaction with hasMany association type)
3. transactions (belongsTo users)

So i need to find all "country_of_residence_history" that contain user and user have all his transactions. BUT! i need filter in condition by one of the transactions attribute. I know that CakePHP ORM do not provide where conditions for hasMany contains, as the CakePHP ORM will use an additional query to retrieve containments of that type. But how can i do that?

Here is my example:

```
            $cond['Transactions.unit_id'] = $this->request->data['unit_id'];
            $cond['Transactions.status'] = 'confirmed';

            $query = $this->CorHistory->find('all')->contain([
                'Users' => ['fields' => ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name']]
            ])->join([
                'table' => 'transactions',
                'alias' => 'Transactions',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => [
                    'Transactions.user_id = CorHistory.user_id',
                ]
            ])->where($cond)->select($this->CorHistory)->select($this->CorHistory->Users->Transactions);
```

And in the very end its do the trick cuz of INNER join, if there is no more then one transaction... and if i provide a unit_id that do not exist it will return empty array.

So in the very end i need result like:

```
     [
        {
            'id' => (int),
            'user_id' => (int),
            'cor_before' => (string),
            'cor_after' => (string),
            'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime),
            'user' => object(App\Model\Entity\User) {
                'id' => (int),
                'first_name' => (string),
                'last_name' => (string),
                'Transactions' => [
                    {
                        'id' => (string),
                        'user_id' => (int),
                        'unit_id' =>(int),
                        'status' => (string) 
                    },
                    {
                        'id' => (string),
                        'user_id' => (int),
                        'unit_id' =>(int),
                        'status' => (string) 
                    },
                ],
            }
        },
    ]
```

How to write a query that gonna find and get all that data and able to filter by "is user have at least one transaction in a specific unit"

Comment: I think that `matching` may be what you need to use here, but I'm not sure if it works in this particular scenario. If you want to find only users that have transactions, it would work, but it's more complicated when finding only things related to "users that have transactions". Might need to juggle the query around a bit to make it work.

Comment: `matching()` would work, but I'd suggest `innerJoinWith()` instead, as the former will modify the select list, which could cause problems when grouping, which would be required for a `hasMany` association. **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799094/how-to-filter-by-conditions-for-associated-models**