# How to query data that is associated with a specific join table entry?

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-4.x

I have 2 tables with has many relationship: `Users` and `Tests`, an the join table generated with bake that associates both `TestsUsers`.

In `TestsUsers`, I have 2 extra fields (besides `user_id` and `test_id`) named `score` and `date`. For adding a record for the first time, I manually crafted the entity in `TestsController` (creating a `$test` entity adding `test.id`, `user.id`, and `user._joinData`) and used `link()` for saving the data.

I'm having trouble in retrieving that record for editing. So far, in the index view (shows all records and has edit and delete actions), I'm passing 3 parameters to the edit function: `test_id`, `user_id` and `TestsUsers_id`.

I've used:

```php
$this->Tests->get(($test_id), [
    'contain' => 'Users',
    function ($q) use ($user_id) {
        return $q->where(['Users.id' => $user_id])  
    }
]])
```

and the result is:

```
test
    (test info)
    users
        [0]
           user_id=1
           (user info)
           _joinData
                   id=1
        [1]
           user_id=1
           (user info)
           _joinData
                    id=2
```

The question is, how do I access `_joinData` level in `get()` for using its id.

P.S. = I'm not allowed to load or use the `TestsUsers` model.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "access _joinData level in get()"? In the data you receive back from `get`? Or do you want to use it somehow in the call you're making *to* `get`?

Comment: Hi, sorry, english is not my first language, what I ment is how do i have access to that _joinData so i can compare the id in there (testsUsers_id) with the id of the record to edit (testsUsers_id). I'm giving the controller 3 parameters, user_id, test_id and testsUsers_id(_joinData), or how do I get() or find() the records from those 3 table matching those parameters without using TestsUsers table,I only manage to use only 2 parameters

Comment: In brief, I need to retrieve an existing record from the join table TestsUsers, using the ids of the user, the test and testsUsers as parameters. That would be used for updating that record

Comment: Ah, you want to get back something like what your test data is showing, but with only the one user record that has `_joinData` matching the specified ID for it? I'm actually not sure how to do that off the top of my head, but hopefully with the clarification someone will be able to help.

Comment: exactly, thanks anyway

Comment: What the right way would be, would depend on whether you want to filter `Tests` too, ie if for the given `$user_id`, no join table entry exists that matches `$UsersTests_id`, should the `Tests` record with `$test_id` still be retrieved (with no `Users`), or not (the latter would result in an exception when using `get()`)?

Comment: Yes, I want to filter by `Tests` too because I need to show `Users.name` and `Tests.name` in the edit view related to that record. I'm new to cake and programming, so, as far as I know it would be like an `inner-join` between `Users` and `Tests` adding the data on `TestsUsers`. I'm currently trying with filtering by `test_id` containing `Users` (also filtering by `user_id`) and iterating the result, saving in an array the matching `TestsUsers_id`. From there I give shape to the entity I pass to the view. I think that last approach is suboptimal, do you have other suggestion or path to follow?

Answer (score 1):

With your explanation in the comments, that the join table row's existence should affect whether `Tests` is being retrieved, you'd generally need to join with your association's tables, and apply the required conditions to filter your results.

Additionally you'd need to apply the same conditions for `contain()`, as that is a separate query that will not affect anything but itself, and its results will afterwards be merged into the `Tests` result on PHP level.

A basic example:

```php
$test = $this->Tests
    ->find()
    ->contain('Users', function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) use ($user_id, $TestsUsers_id) {
        return $query
            ->where([
                'Users.id' => $user_id,
                'TestsUsers.id' => $TestsUsers_id,
            ]);
    })
    // This will join in the join table as well as the target table,
    // hence conditions for the former can be applied as well
    ->innerJoinWith('Users', function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) use ($user_id, $TestsUsers_id) {
        return $query
            ->where([
                'Users.id' => $user_id,
                'TestsUsers.id' => $TestsUsers_id,
            ]);
    })
    ->where([
        'Tests.id' => $test_id,
    ])
    // Grouping is probably not required as the uniqueness of the join
    // table's primary key should already restrict things to one row
    ->group('Tests.id')
    ->firstOrFail();
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Filtering by Associated Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data)**
- **[How to filter by conditions for associated models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799094/how-to-filter-by-conditions-for-associated-models/26800203)**

Comment: thank you very much, it works perfectly. I wasn't targeting `TestsUsers` table because i was told it was not recommended , but for this particular case it seems necessary.

Comment: sorry to bother again, I edited the "extra fields" data in the join table and made a `patchEntity` to modify the query entity with the updated data. Using `$this->Tests->save($test,['associated' => ['Users']]))`, instead of saving the record, it deletes every record in the DDBB with that `test_id` leaving only the oldest record. I only need to modify the extra fields in `TestsUsers`, not `test_id` nor `user_id`.

Comment: @JuanManuelGonzalezCarrascos That's a completely different problem, so I'd suggest that you post a new question where there's room for explaining things in detail, show your association set up, code examples, etc.